How to get an inhibitor lock for a service in C language?
I am making a service and I need to know when the system is about to shutdown, in order to perform a last action and finish the service.
Following Inhibitor Locks documentation (Taking Delay Locks) I wrote the code below; it receives the file descriptor (which is always 0 by the way), however, it's not receiving PrepareForShutdown signal (neither when running systemd-inhibit --list I'm able to list my delay lock).
Here is a snippet of my code:
// (...)

static int inhibitor_lock_fd = -1;
static GDBusConnection *login1_proxy = NULL;
static GMainLoop *login1_loop;

int main (void)
{
  GError *error = NULL;

  login1_proxy = g_bus_get_sync (G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);

  if (error != NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to get login1_proxy: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      return 1;
    }

  take_inhibitor_lock ();

  g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe (login1_proxy,
                                      "org.freedesktop.login1",           // sender
                                      "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager",   // interface
                                      "PrepareForShutdown",               // member
                                      "/org/freedesktop/login1",          // object_path
                                      NULL,
                                      G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                      on_prepare_for_shutdown_signal,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL);

  login1_loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  g_main_loop_run (login1_loop);

  g_main_loop_unref (login1_loop);
  g_object_unref (login1_proxy);

  return 0;
}

int take_inhibitor_lock (void)
{
  GError *error = NULL;
  GVariant *response = NULL;

  if (inhibitor_lock_fd >= 0)
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

  // Call function to get a lock fd
  response =
  g_dbus_connection_call_sync (login1_proxy,
                               "org.freedesktop.login1",         // bus_name
                               "/org/freedesktop/login1",        // object_path
                               "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager", // interface_name
                               "Inhibit",                        // method_name
                               g_variant_new ("(ssss)",
                                              "shutdown",
                                              "My service",
                                              "Perform last task",
                                              "delay"),
                               NULL,
                               G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                               -1,
                               NULL,
                               &error);

  if (error != NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to get inhibitor lock: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      g_object_unref (login1_proxy);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  // Get the lock fd from the GVariant
  g_variant_get (response, "(h)", &inhibitor_lock_fd);

  // Free memory
  g_variant_unref (response);
  g_object_unref (login1_proxy);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void
on_prepare_for_shutdown_signal (GDBusConnection* connection,
                                const gchar* sender_name,
                                const gchar* object_path,
                                const gchar* interface_name,
                                const gchar* signal_name,
                                GVariant* parameters,
                                gpointer user_data)
{
  printf ("on_prepare_for_shutdown_signal called\n");

  // Parse GVariant parameters to get boolean b
  if (b)
    {
      // do my work
      close (inhibitor_lock_fd);
      inhibitor_lock_fd = -1;
    }
}

